# Variable length of input dialogue box in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using inputdlg in MatLab to enter cost of component:

```
x= inputdlg( cellstr( num2str((1:N).', 'Input cost of component %d') ) );
x=str2double(x);
```

where `N` is no of component. This is to make a array of cost.
Problem is, this is good for a certain value of `N`, i.e `N=13`, after which it became difficult to view and enter data.
I have `40` component.

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: inputdlg doesn't support adding a scroll bar, so you could either build your own gui with a scrollbar, or put the inputdlg call in a loop that repeats N=10 4 times (to get 40 components).

Comment: Thanks Trogdor..                                                        EWit                                                                   I want to make dialogue box to be more convenient to enter data. Any other suggestions